# Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) dependencies

Tags: frameworks, dependencies, chromium, chromium-embedded

Looking for a nice and efficient way to render GUI in a game engine I gave a look at the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF). From what I've seen it is doing is job nicely but I'm wondering what are the requirement and dependencies for the CEF.

For each platform I've seen in the source code dependencies to a specific toolkit (gtk for Linux, Win32 API for Windows and so on) Would it run on platforms other than the desktop platforms ? Like Android, iOS, and consoles (Playstation, Xbox) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chromium is switching to Aura UI. CEF on Windows is already using Aura, Linux will use Aura instead of GTK soon. You can [read](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-dev/J72Iv9wtTzw/discussion) here on what is Aura. In short it's a non-native UI toolkit, the only native element is the toplevel window, everything inside is drawn by chrome.

CEF currently supports only Windows/Linux/OSX. CEF may support Android in the future but there is no schedule at this time. Try searching the CEF Forum for "android": http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/search.php?keywords=android

For now, on Android you could use Chromview:
https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview